# Audio file not playing entirely in voice channel

Tags: node.js, audio, discord.js

With a bot, I'm trying to play an audio file (mp3) within an audio channel, using discord.js, ffmpeg and opusscript.

Basically, that's how it works :

```
bot.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.author.bot) return;
    if (msg.content.substring(0,3) == "fp!") {
        var audioID = msg.content.substring(3,msg.length);
        var channel = msg.member.voiceChannel;

        if (!channel) msg.channel.send("T'es pas dans un vocal, con.");
        else {
            msg.member.voiceChannel.join()
            .then((connection) => {
              connection.playFile(`./audios/${audioID}.mp3`);
            });
        } 
      }  
        return;

});
```

So, the audio plays, but it stops before its end (for a 5s audio file, it stops after 3s for example). The bot stays in the channel, I can play again, but for all my files it stops before the end.
How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a know bug, there are not really any fixes for it exept installing discord.js master wich has a full voice rewrite by doing: `npm i discordjs/discord.js`

Comment: When I install it, the bot doesn't even connect to the channel and repeat "T'es pas dans un vocal, con." twice, which is supposed to be said when I'm not in a voice channel while typing the command (I was in), and only once.. weird

Comment: Master aka v12 has breaking changes so you need to change your code.